# Define all constants $c$ that satisfy $CC^{-1}=I$, when $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### Question:

We have matrix C defined as:

$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & c \\
-2 & 3 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now find all $c$ values that satisfy $CC^{-1}=I$, when $c \in \mathbb{R}$

### My solution:

Now matrix is non-singular (reversible) when

**(a)** It's deterimant is non zero $\det(c)\neq 0$

**(b)** has to be $n\times n$ matrix (square)

**(c)** when it has $I_n$ $n$ times meaning diagonal entries are non-zero. If $I_{ni}=0$ it means that $\det(c)=0$ is possible outcome. Which then would mean it's singular.

In matrix $C$ when $c \in R$ it has to be reversible since all the requirements are met. $C$ is reversible with all real values of $c$.

---

Now i have some degree of uncertainty whether my solution is correct or not. I would like to have some feedback if there is something wrong with the reasoning in this or if this is correct. That would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

### Edit:

It appears that when $c=17$ matrix $C$ becomse singular.
[Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,3,17%7D,%7B-2,3,2%7D,%7B-1,2,3%7D%7D%5E-1) approves this but what might be the reason ?

Comment: I think $c = 17$ makes the matrix singular.

Comment: @TheoBendit Wolframalpha approves this. Do you know reason for this ? Mind sharing how did you come up with this ?

Comment: Determinant is $17-c$. As you said in point (a). Det must be $\ne 0$ but if $c=17$ det is 0, therefore matrix is invertible for all $c\ne 17$

Comment: @Raffaele Yes this makes sense now. I've should have computed it first in the first place.

Comment: @Tuki I typically go to absurd lengths to avoid calculating a determinant or doing row reduction. What I did was looked for a linear combination of the first two columns that would produce the third column (for some value of $c$). After trial and error, I settled upon $5(-2, -1) + 4(3, 2) = (2, 3)$ (the second two coordinates of the column vectors), so in order for this linear combination to remain consistent, I set $c = 5 \cdot 1 + 4 \cdot 3 = 17$. But the determinant calculation is easier. Row reduction isn't a bad option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cofactor expansion along the first row gives:

$$1(9-4) - 3(-6 + 2) + c(-4 + 3) $$

Whenever this quantity (the determinant) is non-zero, $C$ is invertible, $C^{-1}$ exists, and $CC^{-1} = I$ by definition. Solving the above, $C$ is invertible whenever $c \not = 17$.

EDIT: I would also like to add that "(c) ....meaning diagonal entries are non-zero." is not true. A square matrix with $1$'s everywhere has non-zero diagonal entries but it's very much singular.

Answer (score 1):

Determine all $c$ such that $\det(C) \ne 0$. For such $C$ we then have that $C$ is invertible and hence $CC^{-1}=I$.

Comment: meaning $c$ could be any value $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and it would be invertible with any value of $c$ ? All values $c \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $CC^{-1}=I$ ?

Comment: No ! Compute $\det(C)$. Then you should get $\det(C)=17-c$. Hence for each $c$ with $ c \ne 17$, the matrix $C$ is invertible.